# Access denied error

Tags: c++

The code i have here to convert string to class complex...

```
void StrtoComplex(char *temp)
    {
        int i;

        for(i = 0; i < strlen(temp); i++)
        {
            if(temp[i] == 'j' || temp[i] == 'i')
                break;
        }

        real = atof(temp);//takes till the last valid char so after + or whitespace it ignores
        imag = atof(temp + i + 1);

        sprintf(complexStr, "%f +j%f", real, imag);
    }
```

it compiles but when running it executes all statements (with proper values....complexStr also has correct string...) but then goes back to sprintf statement and says access denied

ok here is the rest of the code....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>

//Most string operations require the std namespace
using namespace std;


//namespace helps divide global access into subaccess blocks providing data encapsulation
//If required to use any defined within a namespace use scope resolution
namespace Complex
{
    /*This is the Complex class which is asscociated with its corresponding string holding
    the complex representation
    DATA MEMBERS:
    real --------- real part of the complex number
    imag --------- imaginary part of the complex number
    complexstr --- string stream which holds the complex representation
    MEMBER FUNCTIONS
    */
    class complex
    {
        double real;
        double imag;
        char complexStr[50];

    public:
        complex(double re = 0, double im = 0)
        {
            real = re;
            imag = im;
            sprintf(complexStr, "%f +j%f",real,imag);
        }

        complex(complex &t)
        {
            real = t.real;
            imag = t.imag;
        }

        void StrtoComplex(char *temp)
        {
            int i;

            for(i = 0; i < strlen(temp); i++)
            {
                if(temp[i] == 'j' || temp[i] == 'i')
                    break;
            }

            real = atof(temp);//takes till the last valid char so after + or whitespace it ignores
            imag = atof(temp + i + 1);

            sprintf(complexStr, "%f +j%f", real, imag);
        }

        friend complex operator+(complex &a, complex &b);
        friend complex operator-(complex &a, complex &b);
        friend complex operator-(complex &a);
        friend complex operator*(complex &a, complex &b);
        friend complex operator/(complex &a, complex &b);
        friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &s, complex &t);
        friend istream &operator>>(istream &s, complex &t);
    };

    //overloading + to add complex numbers
    complex operator +(complex &a, complex &b)
    {
        complex t;
        t.real = a.real + b.real;
        t.imag = a.imag + b.imag;
        sprintf(t.complexStr, "%f +j%f", t.real, t.imag);
        return(t);
    }
    //overaloading - to subtract 2 complex no's
    complex operator -(complex &a, complex &b)
    {
        complex t;
        t.real = a.real - b.real;
        t.imag = a.imag - b.imag;
        sprintf(t.complexStr, "%f +j%f", t.real, t.imag);
        return(t);
    }

    //overloading unary -
    complex operator -(complex &a)
    {
        complex t(-a.real, -a.imag);
        sprintf(t.complexStr, "%f +j%f", t.real, t.imag);
        return(t);
    }

    //overloading * to multiply 2 complex no's
    complex operator *(complex &a, complex &b)
    {
        complex t;
        t.real = (a.real*b.real) - (a.imag*b.imag);
        t.imag = (a.real*b.imag) + (a.imag*b.real);
        sprintf(t.complexStr, "%f +j%f", t.real, t.imag);
        return(t);
    }
    //overloading / to divide 2 complex no's
    complex operator /(complex &a, complex &b)
    {
        complex t;
        t.real = ((a.real*b.real) + (a.imag*b.imag))/(b.real*b.real + b.imag*b.imag);
        t.imag = ((a.real*b.imag) - (a.imag*b.real))/(b.real*b.real + b.imag*b.imag);
        sprintf(t.complexStr, "%f +j%f", t.real, t.imag);
        return(t);
    }

    ostream &operator<<(ostream &s, complex &t)
    {
        s<<t.complexStr;
        return s;
    }

    istream &operator>>(istream &s, complex &t)
    {
        char *temp;

        s>>temp;
        t.StrtoComplex(temp);
        return s;
    }
}

namespace Discrete
{
    using Complex::complex;
    class signal
    {
        complex *sig_Data;

        int range_start, range_end, zero_pt;

    public:
        signal()
        {
            sig_Data = NULL;
            range_start = range_end = zero_pt = 0;
        }

        signal(complex i)
        {
            sig_Data = new complex(i);
            range_start = range_end = zero_pt = 0;
        }

        signal(int r_start, int r_end, int z_pt)
        {
            range_start = r_start;
            range_end = r_end;
            zero_pt = z_pt;
            int arr_ind = r_end - r_start;

            sig_Data = new complex [arr_ind];
        }

        signal(signal &s)
        {
            sig_Data = s.sig_Data;
            range_start = s.range_start;
            range_end = s.range_end;
            zero_pt = s.zero_pt;
        }

        void StrtoSig(char *temp)
        {
            int arr_ind = 0;
            char *tok;

            if(!*temp) return;

            tok = temp;
            zero_pt = 0;
            //
            int flag;

            for(int i = 0; i < (flag = strlen(temp)); i++)
            {
                tok++;
                if(*tok == '^') zero_pt = arr_ind;
                if(*tok == ',') arr_ind++;
            }
            range_start = 0 - zero_pt;
            range_end = arr_ind - zero_pt;

            sig_Data = new complex [arr_ind];
            tok = temp+1;
            for(int i = 0; i <= arr_ind; i++)
            {
                if(*tok == '^') tok++;
                sig_Data[i].StrtoComplex(tok);
                while(*tok != ',' || *tok != '}'|| *tok != '\0') tok++;
            }
        }

        complex operator[](int i)
        {
            if(i >= range_start && i <= range_end) return sig_Data[zero_pt+i];
            else return complex(0);
        }

        void timeScale(float t)
        { 
            if(t!=0)
            {
                int range = abs((int)((range_end - range_start)/t));
                int flag = 0;
                complex *sig=new complex[range];
                for(int i = 0; i < range; i++)
                {   
                    if(((long)(range_start + i)/t) == (range_start + i)/t)
                        sig[flag++] = sig_Data[i];
                }
                sig_Data = sig;
                range_start = (range_start)/t;
                range_end = (range_end)/t;
                zero_pt = (zero_pt)/t;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"time scaling not possible. Scaling factor is invalid.";
                return;
            }
        }

        //time shifting function
        void timeShift(int i)
        {
            if(i != 0)
            { 
                range_start -= i; 
                range_end -= i;
                zero_pt += i;
            }
            return;
        }

        friend signal operator+(signal &a, signal &b);
        friend signal operator-(signal &a, signal &b);
        friend signal operator-(signal &a);
        friend signal operator*(signal &a, signal &b);

        friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &s, signal &t);
        friend istream &operator>>(istream &s, signal &t);
    };

    //Overloading + operator
    signal operator+(signal &a, signal &b)
    {
        int r_start = min(a.range_start, b.range_start);
        int r_end = max(a.range_end, b.range_end);
        int z_pt = max(a.zero_pt, b.zero_pt);
        signal temp(r_start, r_end, z_pt);
        for(int i = r_start; i < r_end; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = a[i] + b[i];
        }
        return temp;
    }

    //Overloading - operator
    signal operator-(signal &a, signal &b)
    {
        int r_start = min(a.range_start, b.range_start);
        int r_end = max(a.range_end, b.range_end);
        int z_pt = max(a.zero_pt, b.zero_pt);
        signal temp(r_start, r_end, z_pt);
        for(int i = r_start; i < r_end; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = a[i] - b[i];
        }
        return temp;
    }

    //Overloading unary- operator
    signal operator-(signal &a)
    {
        signal temp = a;
        for(int i = a.range_start; i < a.range_end; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = -a[i];
        }
        return temp;
    }

    //Overloading * operator
    signal operator*(signal &a, signal &b)
    {
        int r_start = min(a.range_start, b.range_start);
        int r_end = max(a.range_end, b.range_end);
        int z_pt = max(a.zero_pt, b.zero_pt);
        signal temp(r_start, r_end, z_pt);
        for(int i = r_start; i < r_end; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = a[i] * b[i];
        }
        return temp;
    }

    ostream &operator<<(ostream &s, signal &t)
    {
        int arr_ind = t.range_end - t.range_start;
        s<<"{";
        for(int i = 0; i < arr_ind; i++)
        {
            if(i == t.zero_pt)
                s<<" ^"<<t[i];
            else
                s<<" "<<t[i];
        }
        s<<"}";
        return s;
    }

    istream &operator>>(istream &s, signal &t)
    {
        char *ip;
        s>>ip;
        t.StrtoSig(ip);
        return s;
    }
}

namespace Parser
{
    using Discrete::signal;
    enum types { DELIMITER = 1, VARIABLE, NUMBER, SIGNAL };

    const int NUMVARS = 26; // No. of variable names .....the alphabet
    class parser
    {
        char *exp_ptr; //points to the expression
        char token[80]; //holds current token
        char tok_type; //holds token's type
        signal vars[NUMVARS]; //holds variable's values

        void eval_exp1(signal &result);
        void eval_exp2(signal &result);
        void eval_exp3(signal &result);
        void eval_exp4(signal &result);
        void eval_exp5(signal &result);
        void eval_exp6(signal &result);
        void eval_time1(signal &result);
        void eval_time2(signal &result);

        void atom(signal &resutl);
        void get_token(), putback();
        void serror(int error);
        signal find_var(char *s);
        int isdelim(char c);

    public:
        parser();
        signal eval_exp(char *exp);
    };

    //Parser constructor
    parser::parser()
    {
        int i;

        exp_ptr = NULL;
        for(i = 0; i < NUMVARS; i++) vars[i] = (signal) 0;
    }

    //Parser entry point
    signal parser::eval_exp(char *exp)
    {
        signal result;

        exp_ptr = exp;

        get_token();
        if(!*token)
        {
            serror(2);//no expression present
            return (signal) 0;
        }

        eval_exp1(result);
        if(*token) serror(0); //last token must be null
        return result;
    }

    //Process an assignment
    void parser::eval_exp1(signal &result)
    {
        int slot;
        char ttok_type;
        char temp_token[80];

        if(tok_type == VARIABLE)
        {
            //save old token
            strcpy(temp_token, token);
            ttok_type = tok_type;
            //compute the index of the variable
            slot = toupper(*token) - 'A';

            get_token();
            if(*token != '=')
            {
                putback();//return curent token
                //restore old token - not assignment
                strcpy(token, temp_token);
                tok_type = ttok_type;
            }

            else
            {
                get_token(); //get the next part of the exp
                eval_exp2(result);
                vars[slot] = result;
                return;
            }
        }

        eval_exp2(result);
    }

    //Add or subtract two terms
    void parser::eval_exp2(signal &result)
    {
        register char op;
        signal temp;

        eval_exp3(result);
        while((op = *token) == '+' || op == '-')
        {
            get_token();
            eval_exp3(temp);
            switch (op)
            {
            case '-':
                result = result - temp;
                break;
            case '+':
                result = result + temp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //Multiply or divide two factors
    void parser::eval_exp3(signal &result)
    {
        register char op;
        signal temp;

        eval_exp4(result);
        while((op = *token) == '*' || op == '&')
        {
            get_token();
            eval_exp4(temp);
            switch(op)
            {
            case '*':
                result = result * temp;
                break;
            case '&':
                //Convolution if possible
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    //Evaluate a unary + or -
    void parser::eval_exp4(signal &result)
    {
        register char op;

        op = 0;
        if((tok_type == DELIMITER) && *token == '+' || *token == '-')
        {
            op = *token;
            get_token();
        }

        eval_exp5(result);
        if(op == '-') result = -result;
    }

    //Process a parenthesized expression
    void parser::eval_exp5(signal &result)
    {
        if(*token == '(')
        {
            get_token();
            eval_exp2(result);
            if(*token != ')')
                serror(1);
            get_token();
        }
        else atom(result);
    }

    //Get the value of a number or a variable
    void parser::atom(signal &result)
    {
        switch(tok_type)
        {
        case VARIABLE:
            result = find_var(token);
            eval_time1(result);
            get_token();
            return;
        case NUMBER:
            result = (signal)atof(token);
            get_token();
            return;
        case SIGNAL:
            result.StrtoSig(token);
            get_token();
            return;
        default:
            serror(0);
        }
    }

    //Time scaling
    void parser::eval_time1(signal &result)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(token[i] != '[' || token[i] != 0) i++;
        if(token[i] == '[')
        {
            eval_time2(result);
            i++;
            float x;
            if((x = atof(&token[i])) != 0)
                result.timeScale(x);//atoi takes care of the + and - if existing in the string
        }
    }

    //Time shifting
    void parser::eval_time2(signal &result)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(token[i] != '[' || token[i] != 0) i++;
        if(token[i] == '[')
        {
            i++;
            while(token[i] != '+' || token[i] != '-' || ']') i++;
            result.timeShift(atoi(&token[i+1]));//atoi takes care of the + and - existing in the string
        }
    }

    //Return a token to the input stream
    void parser::putback()
    {
        char *t;

        t = token;
        for(; *t; t++) exp_ptr--;
    }

    //Display a syntax error
    void parser::serror(int error)
    {
        static char *e[] = {
            "Syntax Error",
            "Unbalanced Parenthesis",
            "No expression present"
        };
        cout<<e[error]<<endl;
    }

    //Obtain next token
    void parser::get_token()
    {
        register char *temp;

        tok_type = 0;
        temp = token;
        *temp = '\0';

        if(!*exp_ptr) return; //at end of expression

        while(isspace(*exp_ptr)) ++exp_ptr; //skip over the white spaces

        if(strchr("+-*&=()", *exp_ptr))
        {
            tok_type = DELIMITER;
            //advance to the next char
            *temp++ = *exp_ptr++;
        }

        else if(isalpha(*exp_ptr))
        {
            while(!isdelim(*exp_ptr))
            {
                *temp++ = *exp_ptr++;
                if(*exp_ptr == '[')
                {
                    do
                    {
                        *temp++ = *exp_ptr++;
                    } while(*exp_ptr != ']');
                }
            }
            tok_type = VARIABLE;
        }

        else if(isdigit(*exp_ptr))
        {
            while(!isdelim(*exp_ptr)) *temp++ = *exp_ptr++;
            tok_type = NUMBER;
        }

        else if(*exp_ptr == '{') 
        {
            do
            {
                *temp++ = *exp_ptr++;
            } while(*exp_ptr != '}');
            tok_type = SIGNAL;
        }
        *temp = '\0';
    }

    //Return true if c is delimiter
    int parser::isdelim(char c)
    {
        if(strchr("+-*&=()", c) || c == 9 || c == '\r' || c == 0)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }

    //return value of a variable
    signal parser::find_var(char *s)
    {
        if(!isalpha(*s))
        {
            serror(1);
            return signal(0);
        }
        return vars[toupper(*token) - 'A'];
    }
}


void main()
{
    using Parser::parser;

    parser eQuation;
    char expression[100];

    cout<<"Basic Signal Arithmetic Calculator"<<endl;
    cout<<"Use this program to perform basic addition, subtraction and multiplication of signals with time scaling and time shifting"<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Instructions:"<<endl<<"1. Use assignment operation to give values to variables. Enter signals within '{' and '}' and elements seperaed by ','";
    cout<<endl<<"\tExample: x = {12+i6, 13+i5}";
    cout<<endl<<"2. Use '^' before an element to indicate zero position. By default the 1st element is assumed to be at zero position";
    cout<<endl<<"3. You can include time scaling and shifting within the equation by using the '[' and ']'";
    cout<<endl<<"\tExample: x[2n+3] = y + z[n+5] +{2+i3, ^4+i1}";
    cout<<endl<<"4. Type 'exit' to exit the program";
    cout<<endl<<"%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"<<endl;

    do
    {
        cout<<"Enter your equation:"<<endl;
        cin.get(expression, 100);

        if(!strcmp(expression, "exit"))
            break;

        cout<<endl<<"ans: ";
        cout<<endl<<eQuation.eval_exp(expression);
    }while(1);


    getch();
}
```

Please help

Comment: Pretty sure your access defined has nothing to do with the code you're showing us.

Comment: What do you send to this function?

Comment: What's `complexStr` and where did it come from? I see no declaration of `complexStr` in your code.

Comment: More precisely: where are `real`and `ìmag` defined? If defined in some class, is this function a method of the class? If they are defined private in the class, then probably `StrtoComplex` has no access

Comment: ok updated with entire program.... not too sure what part to show.

Comment: Now you provided more than we need :)

Comment: The first code snippet was where VC++ stopped executing so i wasn't sure where else the problem could be. tried to comment out certain parts of the program to no yeild

Comment: Can you tell us what is the input you provide to the program?

Comment: This doesn't want to compile under the version of GCC I have handy, throwing entertaining errors like _error: no matching function for call to ‘Complex::complex::complex(Complex::complex)’_ There's much to be said for not re-using the same identifiers as namespaces, classes and members...

Comment: @Rook It compiles fine using VS2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in the last code of function `StrToSig()`:

```
while(*tok != ',' || *tok != '}'|| *tok != '\0') tok++;
```

Of course, `*tok` will *always* be different from one of these (in fact, to at least two of them). This will run forever, eventually getting `tok` into unaccessible memory. Just correct it to:

```
while(*tok != ',' && *tok != '}'&& *tok != '\0') tok++;
```

Then you have a second problem: the copy constructor for `complex` is bad because it does not copy `complexStr`, so you'll end up with an uninitialised string there.

Using const references instead of values would also improve your program, but this is out of the scope of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in `istream &operator>>(istream &s, complex &t)`.

You create a `char*` that points at nowhere and then ask `cin` to pop data into it. Unfortunately `cin` doesn't allocate memory for you so you pass garbage into your `StrtoComplex` function causing it to crash.

What you really want to do is (to minimize code changes) do the input into a `std::string` and then pull the `.c_str()` out of that to pass into your parser. There are more idiomatic ways using `std::string` throughout in conjunction with for example `std::find` but this should get your farther.

```
istream &operator>>(istream &s, complex &t)
{
    std::string temp;

    std::getline(s, temp);
    t.StrtoComplex(temp.c_str());
    return s;
}
```

Finally note that I would suggest using `std::string` instead of `char[50]` for your complexStr representation as it will make sure there's always enough memory for your needs.

And in closing I'd like to say "never use `sprintf` even if you know you won't overflow", because sometime someone will make an innocuous change to your code or input and overflow the buffer. *Always* use `snprintf` (or `_snprintf` if your compiler has decided to not support C99).

Comment: the suggestion much appreciated but it doesn't seem to solve the issue. This function 'StrtoComplex' is being called from the function 'StrtoSig'when this error is being thrown